# Sharepoint - End date minus Start date = Years?

Tags: sharepoint, wss, date, formulas

I am needing to calculate the number of years between two fields;

Field A
Start Date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Field B 
End Date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Field C
Calc formula display difference between Field A and B in years and months i.e 5.2

Thanks all.

Comment: Where in SharePoint? In a list field, SharePoint Designer workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about Calculated Columns then you need the [DATEDIF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011609811033.aspx)

Also I am assuming that the 5.2 is 5 years and 2 months - not 5 years and .2 of a year - be a bit more specific in your question and you will get better answers.

So

```
= DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"Y") 
  & " years and " & 
  DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"YM")
  & " months "
```

[Examples of common formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/ha011609471033.aspx)